# Copy range from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I am (trying) to use:

```
Sub EOS_Archive()

' Copy currrent CPT loads to archive area

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Dock Door Mover 2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sorts")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Dock Door Mover 2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sorts Archive")

    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column B

        lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get the last cell with data in row 1
    lastCol = wsCopy.Cells(1, wsCopy.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column B

  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data

    ' wsCopy.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy
    wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(2, 2), wsCopy.Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy
    wsDest.Paste Destination:=("B" & lDestLastRow)
    
End Sub
```

This line gives me an error:
wsDest.Paste Destination:=("B" & lDestLastRow)

Essentially, I have data in a worksheet named "Sorts" that begins in "B2". The first row contains headers. The last column is "I2". The number of rows varies each day (typically 35 rows of data). The goal is to copy this data to an archive worksheet named (Sorts Archive) beginning on the last empty row. The columns are the same (B through I).

Not sure what I missed here.

Comment: *"based on data in column B"* would require `lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`. To utilize the [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy), you could use the one-liner `wsCopy.Range("B2", wsCopy.Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(lDestLastRow, "B")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply defining your range on pasting row ambigous. So you need to specify your range as [Sheet].Range([Range]).

To fix your code; you can replace your last two rows with:

```
wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(2, 2), wsCopy.Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
```